# How to add Focus for Alert Dialog Title in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xyz" />
    <EditText 
           android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have an XML layout as above and when I click that xyz button I want to launch my application "Sample App" which will show a dialog.
I have enabled "talkback" application from settings ->Accessibility.
Then once I click xyz button, talkback app is saying "alert.." but its not saying "alert + dialog title". 
But if i start a dialog in my application then its saying the dialog title correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare Your activity in manifest like..

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"           
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
```

Comment: are you declare theme as dialog like android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" ?

Comment: My question is how to make talkback application to say the alert dialog title not to make my application as dialog.